# bootstrap4 navbar-expand- not working in angular5 project

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple navigation bar made with Bootstrap4 in an Angular5 project, the navigation bar looks like this:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-success ">        
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>        
    </nav>
```

According to the bootstrap docs and in an outside `HTML` file where I also tried this code, the navbar should expand when the screensize get small due to this `navbar-expand-sm` Bootstrap4 class. However this is not the case in my project the navbar stays expanded at every screensize like this:

[image: bootstrap4 navbar-expand]

Because it does only not work in the Angular5 project I suspect that Angular5 project interferes with Bootstrap4

Below you can see the structure of my angular project. It is very simple just a header component and a router outlet which in this case outputs the home component:

[image]

### Question:

Why is my navbar expanding even at big screen sizes and how do I fix this?

Comment: I would begin by making sure that you are bringing in the jQuery dependency as the navbar is one of the BS components that require JS.

Comment: Just to clarify `navbar-expand-*` denotes the MINIMUM breakpoint at which the navigation links will be fully visible (outside the hamburger).  With `-sm` you're saying: Let it be visible on Small and Greater.  Is that your intention or are you misinterpreting how the class operates?

Comment: I know how the class operates, I want the navigation to expand (make stack vertically like example picture given) whenever the small breakpoint is reached. However my navbar is expanded at all lenghts.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **button** which will be responsible for collapsing and expanding with `class`=`navbar-toggler`.

Set all the links in a div with classes *`collapse and navbar-collapse`*.
data-target of button should the id of div.

Example is as follows:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
  <button
    class="navbar-toggler btn"
    data-target="#navbarCollapse"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    type="button"
  >
    btn
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
              </li>
          </ul> 
       </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason nav expand is not working because you need to add following library to your package.json:

1. jQuery
2. Popper.js

Please add the JS File for jQuery & popper.js to your angular cli JSON file, so they can included by angular.